# Assuming positive real part of a complex number in Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, complex-numbers

I cannot figure it out how to assume positive real part of a complex number in Sympy.
Example of an Mathematica code:

```
a = InverseFourierTransform[ R/(I omega - lambda) +  Conjugate[R]/(I omega - Conjugate[lambda]), omega, t,   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

Simplify[a, {Re[lambda] < 0, t > 0}]
```

Similar Sympy code:

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()

ω = sym.symbols('omega', real=True, positive=True) 

R, λ = sym.symbols('R, lambda', complex=True)

t = sym.symbols('t', real=True, positive=True)

α = R/(sym.I*ω-λ)+sym.conjugate(R)/(sym.I*ω-sym.conjugate(λ))

sym.inverse_fourier_transform(α, ω, t)
```

How could I assume real part of lambda to be positive? If I assume lambda to have `positive=True`, then sympy assumes `imaginary=False`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [`assumptions`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html)?

Comment: yes, sure. I added assumptions at symbol creation (e.g. lambda = sym.symbols('lambda', complex=True). But it looks like it is not possible to assume positive/negative real value. If I assume positive=True, then this sets the imaginary to False and I do not have a complex number anymore...

Comment: Did you even look at what I linked?

Comment: @AndrasDeak The `assumptions` module does not interact with the rest of SymPy, so it cannot help with this problem (or with any other problem).

Comment: @bro thanks, I didn't know that. I tried it, but I got 0 for the expression to begin with then I got distracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two real symbols x, y, assume x positive, and let `λ` be `x + I*y`.

```
import sympy as sym
ω, x, t = sym.symbols('omega x t', positive=True) 
y = sym.symbols('y', real=True)
R = sym.symbols('R')
λ = x + sym.I*y
α = R/(sym.I*ω-λ)+sym.conjugate(R)/(sym.I*ω-sym.conjugate(λ))    
res = sym.inverse_fourier_transform(α, ω, t)
```

The result is

```
2*pi*R*exp(2*pi*t*(x + I*y)) + 2*pi*exp(2*pi*t*(x - I*y))*conjugate(R)
```

You can then return to single-symbol λ with substitution:

```
λ = sym.symbols('lambda')
res.subs(x + sym.I*y, λ).conjugate().subs(x + sym.I*y, λ).conjugate()
```

obtaining

```
2*pi*R*exp(2*pi*lambda*t) + 2*pi*exp(2*pi*t*conjugate(lambda))*conjugate(R)
```

(The trick with two conjugations is needed because `subs` isn't going to replace `x - I*y` with conjugate(lambda) otherwise.)

---

#### Remarks on assumptions

- `complex=True` is redundant; real numbers are included in complex numbers (7 is a complex number), so this has no effect
- `real=True` is redundant when `positive=True` is given

Comment: Thank you; this works fine! But is there a way to make similar assumptions as in Mathematica? Should I make this a feature proposal? What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean having a single symbol, make an assumption about its real part? That is not possible. Feel free to propose on sympy issue tracker in Github.

Comment: Nice post and discussion! There is a problem that Symbols are changed globally and turning real symbols to complex doesn't work. Is there any solution for that ?